My Table is to wide for the page
I'm not really good in making tables. My table is too wide for the document. Is it posible to use paragraphs in the cells of the table? Or can I change the font size specificly for the table or are there other ways to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance
This is my code:
\begin{table}\label{fig:Tabelle_GPC}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
Probe & ISISI\_10\% & ISISI\_20\% & ISISI\_40\% & ISISISI\_10\% & ISISISI\_40\% & SISIS\_90\% & SIS\_10\% \\ \hline
Styrolanteil {[}\%{]} & $10$ & $20$ & $40$ & $10$ & $40$ & $90$ & $10$ \\ \hline
Isoprenanteil {[}\%{]} & $90$ & $80$ & $60$ & $90$ & $60$ & $10$ & $90$ \\ \hline
$M_{w,gesamt} [\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $380 000$ & $585 000$ & $308 000$ & $410 000$ & $343 000$ & $239 000$ & $423 000$ \\ \hline
PDI & $1,39$ & $1,30$ & $1,49$ & $1,22$ & $1,41$ & $1,09$ & $1,10$ \\ \hline
Blocklänge Styrol $[\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $18 650$ & $58 500$ & $61 600$ & $13 667$ & $45 733$ & $71 700$ & $21 500$ \\ \hline
Blocklänge Isopren $[\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $111 900$ & $156 000$ & $61.600$ & $92.250$ & $51 450$ & $11 950$ & $380 700$ \\ \hline
Probenmasse nach Fraktionierung $[g]$ & $0,36$ & $1,82$ & $3,26$ & $2,33$ & $3,72$ & - & -
\end{tabular}
\caption{Durchschnittliche Molekulargewichte $M_{w,gesamt}$, Polydispersitäten und Blocklängen der Multicoblockpolymere. Zudem wurde die übrig gebliebene Masse nach der Fraktioniereung über Isopropanol und Cyclohexan angegeben.}
\end{table}


Without knowing what your desired width is, it's hard to provide specifics. You mention font sizes; since your tabular environment is enclosed in a table, you could simply specify a font size at the end of \begin{table} (such as small, footnotesize, etc.). If you want the caption to be the same size as the rest of your document, and since you have the caption placed at the bottom, be sure to restore the font size to normalsize before exiting the table.
\begin{table}\label{fig:Tabelle_GPC}\small % font change to small
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
Probe & ISISI\_10\% & ISISI\_20\% & ISISI\_40\% & ISISISI\_10\% & ISISISI\_40\% & SISIS\_90\% & SIS\_10\% \\ \hline
Styrolanteil {[}\%{]} & $10$ & $20$ & $40$ & $10$ & $40$ & $90$ & $10$ \\ \hline
Isoprenanteil {[}\%{]} & $90$ & $80$ & $60$ & $90$ & $60$ & $10$ & $90$ \\ \hline
$M_{w,gesamt} [\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $380 000$ & $585 000$ & $308 000$ & $410 000$ & $343 000$ & $239 000$ & $423 000$ \\ \hline
PDI & $1,39$ & $1,30$ & $1,49$ & $1,22$ & $1,41$ & $1,09$ & $1,10$ \\ \hline
Blocklänge Styrol $[\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $18 650$ & $58 500$ & $61 600$ & $13 667$ & $45 733$ & $71 700$ & $21 500$ \\ \hline
Blocklänge Isopren $[\frac{g}{mol}]$ & $111 900$ & $156 000$ & $61.600$ & $92.250$ & $51 450$ & $11 950$ & $380 700$ \\ \hline
Probenmasse nach Fraktionierung $[g]$ & $0,36$ & $1,82$ & $3,26$ & $2,33$ & $3,72$ & - & -
\end{tabular}\normalsize % restore font before caption
\caption{Durchschnittliche Molekulargewichte $M_{w,gesamt}$, Polydispersitäten und Blocklängen der Multicoblockpolymere. Zudem wurde die übrig gebliebene Masse nach der Fraktioniereung über Isopropanol und Cyclohexan angegeben.}
\end{table}

